# What does Memory Scanning refer to in the Context of Malware Detection Wanna Cry

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, wannacry

When reading https://www.zionsecurity.com/sites/default/files/what_to_expect_from_your_antivirus.pdf
It mentions:

> It is almost impossible to protect against new malware that will use
>   the EternalBlue exploit to propagate except when using next-generation
>   endpoint protection with memory scanning capabilities and exploit
>   detection. Traditional anti-virus without premium features or
>   configured by default will not block the EternalBlue exploit.

I am confused as to what memory scanning capabilities are referring to here. What exactly would these "next generation" anti-virus programs be doing to prevent attacks like wanna cry?